# proc tabulate table with where clause

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with tree variables, three binary variables.

I wrote a proc tabulate

```
proc tabulate data=mydata;
class country var1 var2;
table Country, var1 var2;
run;

    Var1    Var2    
    0   1   0   1
USA 40  50  40  50
AUS 50  20  50  20
IRE 60  40  60  40
DUB 70  50  70  50
```

Here I get the table with the totals of both var 1 var 2 for 0s and 1s.

However I want only the totals of 1s in this cross table. How can I do that.

If I use a where caluse as below, it shows only 1ns both..

```
proc tabulate data=mydata;
class country var1 var2;
table Country, var1 var2;
where var1=1 and var2=2;
run;
```

When I use the above it brings out only the 1s present in both at the sametime. 
Which is not I am looking for.
So the dataset I want is as below.

```
    Var1 Var2
    1   1
USA 50  50
AUS 20  20
IRE 40  40
DUB 50  50
```

Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Change `and` to `or`.

```
   Truth table for
   Var1=1, Var2=1

             Include?
Var1 Var2  AND      OR
0    0      N       N
0    1      N       Y
1    0      N       Y
1    1      Y       Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your variables are coded 0,1 you can ask for the SUM statistic to get the "count" of the number of ones.

```
proc tabulate data=mydata;
   class country;
   var var1 var2;
   table Country, var1*sum var2*sum;
run;
```